# 1С 8.3 (Обычное). Как изменить количество товара в табличной части у конкретного товара?

Tags: 1с

Есть код:

```
//Вызываем процедуру

Процедура ТоварыПриПолученииДанных(Элемент, ОформленияСтрок)

//Проходим цикл ОформленияСтрок

Для Каждого СтрокаТЧ Из ОформленияСтрок Цикл 

//Ставим условие, чтобы менять значение только у "Болты 215"

       Если СтрокаТЧ.ДанныеСтроки.Номенклатура=Справочники.Номенклатура.НайтиПоНаименованию("Болты 215") Тогда
           СтрокаТЧ.ДанныеСтроки.Количество=3;
       КонецЕсли; 

КонецЦикла;

КонецПроцедуры;
```

Пытаюсь для примера изменить количество товара в табличной части (в данном случае у `"Болты 215"`),
но почему-то у всех в списке меняется количество, хотя по логике должен был меняться только у `"Болты 215"`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что здесь не так? Почему так происходит? Прошелся с отладкой, тоже как-то не помогло.

Comment: Откройте конфигуратор, Сделайте скриншот: Форма - Свойства - События; Приложите к вопросу

Comment: и еще скриншот: ТаблЧасть Товары - Свойства - События

Comment: По наименованию искать не лучшая мысль